# database permissions match whoever is running PowerShell script instead of those specified in connection string

Tags: sql, powershell, connection-string, database-permissions, integrated-security

I want SQL Server permissions to conform to the ID I specify in the connection string, NOT those of whoever happens to be running the PowerShell script (usually me).

For example, I have a table called “MyTable” which I can update but which “TestIDRestricted” cannot.

I log onto the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio as “TestIDRestricted” and run the following query

```
select MyField
from MyTable
where ID = 2
```

and I see it returns "4".  I now try to update:

```
update MyTable
set MyField = 5
where ID = 2
```

As expected, I get the following failure result:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'MyTable', database 'mydb', schema 'dbo'.
```

Next I run the following UpdateProblem.ps1 PowerShell script:

```
$ConnectionString = "Server=MyServer\MSSQL2012;Database=mydb;User Id= TestIDRestricted;Password=secretpasswd;"
$ConnectionString = $ConnectionString + "Trusted_Connection = yes;Persist Security Info=False"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$sqlConnection.Open()
$sqlCommand = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$updateSQL ="update MyTable set MyField = 5 where ID = 2"
$sqlCommand.CommandText = $updateSQL 
write-host $updateSQL
#following command should fail
$sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
$sqlConnection.close()
```

I expect this update to fail because I am NOT specifying integrated security in the connection string.  But when I log back onto the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio as “TestIDRestricted” and again run the following query

```
select MyField
from MyTable
where ID = 2
```

I see it returns "5".  So the update succeeded even though I expect it to fail.  From what I can tell, the reason it succeeded is because the SQL permissions are based on my ID using integrated security instead of the security associated with the ID I use in the connection string.

How can I get the script to use the permissions associated with the ID I specify in the connection string instead of using my ID’s permissions that seem to follow along with integrated security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting Trusted_Connection to TRUE; this almost certainly means you're connecting with the credentials of the current user, not those specified in the connection string.
Try:

```
$ConnectionString = "Server=MyServer\MSSQL2012;Database=mydb;User Id= TestIDRestricted;Password=secretpasswd;"
$ConnectionString = $ConnectionString + "Trusted_Connection = no;Persist Security Info=False"
```

Comment: When I use “Trusted_Connection = yes”, that was short-circuiting the user and password specified in the connection string and forcing to use integrated security, no matter whether or not I set Integrated Security to “true”, “false” or “SSPI”.
The real problem was the password: it contained a “$” sign which kinda screws things up.  I suspect it’s because “$” signifies a variable – even inside quotes.  I have to escape that special character with a “`”.
Now I it uses the proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just comment out the second line:

```
$ConnectionString = "Server=MyServer\MSSQL2012;Database=mydb;User Id= TestIDRestricted;Password=secretpasswd;"
' $ConnectionString = $ConnectionString + "Trusted_Connection = yes;Persist Security Info=False"
```

(Is this VB?)

Comment: PowerShell, not VB.  Like I said in my reply to the other post, "Trusted_Connection = yes" was, indeed the problem.  I had used it to unknowingly "short-circuit" the user I specified.  The real problem was the password: it contained a “$” sign which kinda screws things up.  I suspect it’s because “$” signifies a variable in PowerShell – even inside quotes.  I have to escape that special character with a “`”.